# Setting DataSource of BindingSource throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception for only me

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource`, and I'm setting its `DataSource` to a `SortableSearchableList<MyCustomType>` object.  The line `materialPropertiesData.DataSource = _sortedMaterialPropertiesList;` is throwing the following exception:

[image]

However, if I look at the `_sortedMaterialPropertiesList`, the date is not what the exception claims it is:

[image]

I am the only one in my team that is experiencing this.  This is the first exception that is thrown out of a large number of exceptions that are thrown with almost every interaction I have with the `Form`.  I'm not sure how to debug this since I am the only experiencing this.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can identify what is going on?  Thanks!

p.s. Please let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: Are you binding to a datetimePicker? I am experiencing something similar

Comment: Something similar. It is a control from devexpress. I think you can cause it to bring up a date picker calendar pop up, but we are just using the base control to format our input.

Comment: I have documented a similar problem here
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15824070/edit

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: does it work fine when running the .exe?

Comment: It seems to work if I continue the process with my normal interaction with the interface.  I just wish I knew why Visual Studio seems to think there is a problem.